# iPhone checking for existence of AVCaptureSession Class

Tags: objective-c, ios4, avcapturesession

I have integrated a library that uses AVCaptureSession to capture a photo from the camera. As the AVCaptureSession is only available on [iOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29) 4 devices, I want to disable this integrated functionality for older devices.

I know that it should be done by weak-linking the AVFoundation Framework and checking for function existence. Weak-linking is easy to do, but which function should I check for existence here? AVCaptureSession is a class and not a function.

Are there some sample code available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `NSClassFromString`:

```
Class NSClassFromString ( NSString *aClassName );
```

You can then guard usage of that class with something like this:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureSession")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: It worked! thanks alot. For note, I had to also weak-link other libraries like CoreVideo and UIKit.

Comment: `objc_getClass` is more efficient.